# Error thrown inside jquery file - odd syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

My web page threw an error and i landed on the following code (inside jquery .js file):

```
trigger: function() {
  return this !== _() && this.focus ? (this.focus(), !1) : void 0
}
```

What does the part `(this.focus(), !1)` mean. Is this even possible? As far as i know, a function can only return one value.

Comment: It'll probably only return the `!1` and trigger the `this.focus()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part specifically executes `this.focus()` then returns `false`. The comma completes one statement before moving onto the next and the brackets contain the statements to prevent any other syntax error occuring from including the comma.

The syntax is very strange, but the most likely cause of that is minification. The original code propbably looked something like this:

```
trigger: function () {

    if (this !== _() && this.focus) {

        this.focus();
        return false;

    }

}
```

JavaScript returns `undefined` if nothing else is specified (and `void 0` is just a shorter way of writing that) so the function can be expanded to something like this:

```
trigger: function () {

    if (this !== _() && this.focus) {

        this.focus();
        return false;

    }

    return undefined;

}
```

To reduce bytes, the minifier will combine the two `return` statements into a single one. As you can see from the code, the single `return` statement would have to return `false` if certain conditions are met and after `this.focus()` has executed or `undefined` if the conditions are not met. That's what the statement you queried does.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks :) I'll probably never use that syntax, would just lead to hard readable code.

Comment: It's a good idea to never use that syntax. A minifier will generate it because they prioritise small size over readability but for source code, it' well worth prioritising readability over size - it makes maintenance a lot easier